# WordPress + CloudFront Flexible SSL ends up in redirect loop (https)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudflare

Having problems accessing the admin over https when it's setup behind CloudFront Flexible SSL.

The admin works fine when accessing over http, but as soon as I change to secure https it ends up in a redirect loop.

I'm adding the following line to `wp-config.php` to force SSL in the admin.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Comment: The information in our knowledge base about [redirect loops and Flexible SS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-)L should also help.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is due to the fact that CloudFlare's Flexible SSL operates as a reverse proxy and connects to the WordPress installation via `http`.  Wordpress thinks you're connecting via `http` and does a redirect to the `https` resource.  The browser requests the `https` resource from CloudFlare and CloudFlare again requests the resource over `http` from the WordPress server, resulting in another redirect.

Fortunately there's a solution.  CloudFlare sends an http header X-FORWARDED-PROTO that is the protocol used in the connection from the browser to the CloudFlare server.  We can use this to tell WordPress that even though the request is happening over `http`, the link to the browser is over `https`.

In the `wp-config.php` file add the following line:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

It's also crucial that the above line comes before the following line:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

After making that modification the redirect loop will stop and you'll be able to use the admin again.

This ultimately applies to all reverse proxy servers, not just CloudFlare.

Comment: Thank you! the crucial part for me is putting it ABOVE `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: In my case, that didn't fix the problem - then I realized I also needed to invalidate the cloudfront, because it had cached that 301

Answer (score 2):

In my case we getting this problem because I configure CloudFront origin incorrect.

```
cloudfront-> origin -> Origin Protocol Policy -> Match Viewer
```

after this setting my website working fine

Answer (score 0):

in my case, another source of problems was (I know sounds silly) the DefaultRootObject.

I had this error on my CloudFront and WordPress and was the issue of my Too Many Redirects nightmare. I'm posting that because someone falls into the same stupid error like me.

Cheers