# After HTTPS active "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Tags: wordpress, https

In wordpress, i have used nginx and done https the whole site. But when i want to access admin after SSL. I got this

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I have tried many things.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But still i am getting the same issue. So Is there any solution for this ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a SSL Plugin? May it be a server configuration issue?

Comment: I have a ssl plugin. problem is that i cant access the admin.

Comment: I got the solution for it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193575/wordpress-cloudfront-flexible-ssl-ends-up-in-redirect-loop-https/27193576#27193576